# How to get data value in regular js file from vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have component MyComponent.vue where I have data value that constantly changes. I want to pass this value to javascript file(js file should know about changes of value everytime)

Why do I do that? Because  my regular js file is a service layer for axios methods. I can import this file in many other components. The file contains axios methods and urls are dynamic.
I want those urls depend on data variable. This data variable comes from MyComponent.js

So the main goal is to make dynamic urls of axios that depend on data variable

I tried some code but it doesn't work, because js file(CategoryService.js) know nothing about `this.categoryNumber`.

*MyComponent.vue:*

```
<script>
export default {
data() {
return {
categoryNumber: 1
   }
  }
}
</script>
```

*CategoryService.js*

```
import http from "../../../http-common";

let category = "category1";

if (this.categoryNumber === 1) {
    category = "category1";
} if (this.categoryNumber === 2) {
    category = "category2";
}

class CategoryService {
    get(id) {
        return http.get(`/${category}/${id}`);
    }

    update(id, data) {
        return http.put(`/${category}/${id}`, data);
    }

    create(data) {
        return http.post(`/${category}`, data);
    }

    delete(id) {
        return http.delete(`/${category}/${id}`);
    }

    getAll() {
        return http.get(`/${category}/all`);
    }
}

export default new CategoryService();
```

Comment: Why not add one more argument to each method. e.g.  `create(category_number, data) {}` so the methods expect two arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Solar
I just added one more parameter for all urls and put the number of category to it

*CategoryService.js:*

```
class CategoryOneService {
    get(id, category) {
        return http.get(`/${category}/${id}`);
      }

      getAll(category) {
        return http.get(`/${category}/all`);
      }

    }
```

*functions.js:*

```
let catNum = "";

function getQuestion() {

    if (this.categoryNumber === 1) {
        catNum = "category1";
    }

    if (this.categoryNumber === 2) {
        catNum = "category2";
    }
    let questionId = this.questionNumber;
    CategoryOneService.get(questionId, catNum)
        .then(response => {
            this.question = response.data.question;
            this.answer = response.data.answer;

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So with a bit of refactoring, you could easily get this working.

First of all, I would put the if/else logic of your class into it.

For convenience and scalability, I would use a Vuex store that will keep track of your categoryNumber and share it accross all your components.

Then I would bind my service to my Vue instance so I can easily access it in all my components as well as the store and I would pass the latter to my class as a parameter.

For the last part, I don't know the logic in the http-common file so the code I will show you is a bit nasty. But depending on wether or not you bound 'http' to axios, you could make use of [axios interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) to call the `getCategoryNumber()` method in every request.

Here's an idea of the implementation I would go for:

```js
const CategoryService = class CategoryService {

  constructor(store) {
    this._store = store;
    this.category = "category1";
  }

  getCategoryNumber() {
    if (this._store.state.categoryNumber === 1) {
      this.category = "category1";
    }
    if (this._store.state.categoryNumber === 2) {
      this.category = "category2";
    }
    console.log(this.category); // for demo puprose
  }

  get(id) {
    this.getCategoryNumber(); // We could use axios request interceptor instead of calling that in every route, but that works !
    return http.get(`/${this.category}/${id}`);
  }

  update(id, data) {
    this.getCategoryNumber();
    return http.put(`/${this.category}/${id}`, data);
  }

  create(data) {
    this.getCategoryNumber();
    return http.post(`/${this.category}`, data);
  }

  delete(id) {
    this.getCategoryNumber();
    return http.delete(`/${this.category}/${id}`);
  }

  getAll() {
    this.getCategoryNumber();
    return http.get(`/${this.category}/all`);
  }
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    categoryNumber: 1
  },
  mutations: {
    setCategoryNumber(state, payload) {
      state.categoryNumber = payload;
    }
  }
});

// Bind your service to the Vue prototype so you can easily use it in any component with 'this.$service'
// pass it the store instance as parameter
Vue.prototype.$service = new CategoryService(store);

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store, // dont forget to bind your store to your Vue instance
  methods: {
    updateCategoryNumber() {
      // Put here any logic to update the number
      this.categoryNumber = this.categoryNumber === 1 ? 2 : 1;
      this.checkServiceCategoryValue();
    },
    checkServiceCategoryValue() {
      // for demonstration purpose
      this.$service.getCategoryNumber();
    }
  },
  computed: {
    // Look for the store value and update it 
    categoryNumber: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.categoryNumber;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit("setCategoryNumber", value);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h2>number: {{ categoryNumber }}</h2>
  <button type="button" @click="updateCategoryNumber()">
    updateCategoryNumber
  </button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@2.0.0"></script>
```